# Edit an in-progress AWS Mechanical Turk Campaign

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I have started a mechanical Turk campaign where I have forgotten to include instructions to users what to do if a requested item cannot be found.  I'd like to modify the HTML of all the HITs to say, "If X is not found, please put 'NOT FOUND'".

However, I cannot find any options for how to edit a campaign that has been published---if I were to stop the campaign, could I edit it then?  I'd be annoyed to do that because it would seem I would then have to rekey, and re-merge the tasks completed in batch 1 and batch 2.

Is there a best way to do this?

Comment: You should use ExternalHIT for this. That way you can just edit your web page and change the instructions on the fly. It's a lot more convenient I find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, unfortunately.

The closest thing is the [ChangeHITTypeOfHIT operation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ChangeHITTypeOfHITOperation.html), but that only allows you to change properties of the HITType that display to worker (Title, description, QualificationRequirements, Duration, etc.) not the Question (e.g., HTML) content of a HIT.

You'll have to cancel the batch and then start a new one with the corrected text.